# SOAP Web service authentication via Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am planning to create a RestAPI Interface using Flask by consuming SOAP Web Services. The SOAP Web Services which i am using requires username and password for authentication. How can i make users to send credentials via Flask RestAPI so that it authenticate the web services and return the results.

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: Are you sure there's no other option for authentication such as OAuth?

Comment: No OAuth. The SOAP Web services which i am consuming requires basic authentication.

Comment: Are there service your's or third party?

Comment: I am using third party services.